# What does "avoid" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> And then, when they are home again, with all this drama and tragedy
>   behind them, they will slip into old patterns, *avoiding what’s
>   important*, carrying on the way they should.

I checked the longman dictionary[1]. There are some meanings for the verb "avoid":

- to prevent something bad from happening
- avoid doing something
- to stay away from someone or something, or not use
- to deliberately not do something, especially something wrong,
  dangerous, or harmful

I think the second one is more appropriate. But I don't still understand the meaning of the phrase below:

> avoiding what’s important

So, could you please explain it to me?

The full text is here:

> Beverly follows her husband to the staircase. They’ve hastily thrown
>   on some warm clothes and are on their way to the dining room. Her
>   heart races in time with her quick footsteps on the stairs. Despite
>   her deep pity for the dead woman, she almost feels like they have been
>   saved. This crisis has sidelined their own troubles. It’s as if
>   they’ve both been pulled back from the brink they’d faced last night.
>   It’s awful to think so, but she’s hoping that it will prevent them
>   from focusing again on their marriage in the cold, empty light of day.
>   She does not want to go there, now that she knows just how precarious
>   her position is. And then, when they are home again, with all this
>   drama and tragedy behind them, they will slip into old patterns,
>   **avoiding what’s important, carrying on the way they should**. The way
>   they must.

*An Unwanted Guest*  by  Shari Lopena

[1]https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/avoid

Comment: They are failing to address important matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the meanings other than the first. It is ironically describing how in normal life we often avoid (don't do, don't think about, don't mention, don't deal with) some important matters.